# How can I delete all channels in a Discord server?

Tags: discord.js

I am using Discord.js Version 12, and I needed to know how to delete all channels in a Discord server. The newest forum I could find about this is for V11. Any help? Thanks! Code:

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'delall':

}
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to loop through all the `channels` in the `guild` and delete them.

```js
message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(channel => channel.delete())
```

Comment: It's not an async function, how do I fix that?

Comment: `bot.on('message', async message => {` you need to make the function the code is contained in asynchronous `async`

Comment: message.guild.channels.fetch is not a function.

Comment: Fixed my answer, that's my bad